# Untar a specifc folder within tar.gz

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal, osx, tar

How do I untar/uncompress a specific folder within a tar.gz using the terminal/commandline ([Ubuntu 14.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_14.04_LTS_.28Trusty_Tahr.29) (Trusty Tahr))?

Precise:

```
-file.tar.gz
 -- folder1
 -- folder2
```

How to extract...

```
... folder1 -->  ~/locationX
... folder2 --> ~/locationY
```

How can I do this?

**Please notice:**
This is purely related to terminal/commandline and not [Puppet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puppet_%28software%29). This is just one example - I would save roughly 50 additional steps in Puppet, if there is a command to uncompress a specific folder from within a `tar.gz` as I could avoid moving files around...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
tar -xzf file.tar.gz -C ~/locationX folder1 -C ~/locationY folder2
```

The `-C` option means to change to the specified directory before doing the extraction. Specifying filename arguments after the tarfile name restricts the extraction to just those files or directories. And you can repeat this `-C`hanging directories as you do.

Note that this will do the extractions in subdirectories:`folder1` will go into `~/locationX/folder1`, `folder2` will go into `~/locationY/folder2`. You can prevent this by using the `--strip-components` option:

```
tar -xzf file.tar.gz -C ~/locationX --strip-components=1 folder1 \
                     -C ~/locationY --strip-components=1 folder2
```

Also, if the actual prefixes in the tar file are `./folder1` and `./folder2`, as is likely if you created the tar file with `tar -czf file.tar.gz .`, you'll need to include the `./` prefix in the filename arguments, and change to `--strip-components=2`.

Comment: awesome! Apart from the fact that you solved the question I had, I can´t remember when I received such a foreward thinking answer in any forum.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @frank There is the stackexchange community for you. Welcome!

Comment: And I thought http://xkcd.com/1168/